# I am having this error when run a jar file Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/NoSuchF ileException

Tags: java

When trying to run the jar file using java 1.6 I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/NoSuchF
ileException.

But when I run using 1.8, It runs without problem.

Does someone knows what's may be happening?

Comment: Using java8 specific classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` did not exist in Java 1.6

It was added in Java 1.7.

From the [api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException.html):

> public class NoSuchFileException extends FileSystemException
>
> Checked exception thrown when an attempt is made to access a file that does not exist.
>
> Since:
>       1.7

So, since the code in your JAR file uses that class you can only run that JAR with a version of Java >= 1.7

Comment: Well. When developing in netbeans, I chose the binary the source/binary to jdk 6. Isn't that the correct way of compiling to java 1.6?

Comment: You have some code which uses `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` and you want to compile that code to Java 6? How would that work, given that `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` does not exist in the Java 1.6 JDK?

Comment: Maybe the IDE should throw an error when trying to compile that to Java 1.6. Shouldn't it? I actually don't use this class directly, but it's thrown when trying to read a file in the code.

Comment: If the IDE actually **did** attempt to compile that code to Java 1.6 then it would throw a compilation error.

Comment: Well it compiles. But I found some catch clauses throwing that exception "NoSuchFileException" in the class. So I removed it and it doesn't show that error again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchFileException means specified file is not added in the jar.

1. Just Refresh Or Check out the folder structure.
2. Recreate the jar for same.